# LED sometimes don't turn off when a button is pressed

Tags: led

I'm still very new to this but I've put together some code that when a button is pressed, my servo runs continuously, a second button rotates it the other way and a third cancels everything.

A red or green comes on depending on the rotation and this can be one using an IR receiver also.

Issue I'm having is that randomly, 1/5 of the time, the red or green LED does not turn off. I can manually kill it using the third cancel button or just press it a couple times until it turns off as it should on the next push of the button.

Cant work out where im going wrong.

I also find my IR remote works maybe 60% of the time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo1;
int servoPin = 9;
#include "IRremote.h"

/*----- Variables, Pins -----*/


int receiver = 12; // Signal Pin of IR receiver to Arduino Digital Pin 6
int RledPin = 5;
int GledPin = 3;
int buttonApin = 7;
int buttonBpin = 8;
int buttonCpin = 4;
unsigned long elapsedTime;
unsigned long onTime;

/*-----( Declare objects )-----*/
// Setup of proper sequencing for Motor Driver Pins
// In1, In2, In3, In4 in the sequence 1-3-2-4

IRrecv irrecv(receiver);    // create instance of 'irrecv'
decode_results results;     // create instance of 'decode_results'

void setup()
{
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  servo1.attach(servoPin);
  servo1.write(90);
  pinMode(RledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonApin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
  pinMode(buttonBpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonCpin, INPUT_PULLUP);

}

void loop(){

if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW)   // Switch is closed to start LED timer
         {
          digitalWrite(RledPin, HIGH);  // Red LED comes On
          digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);  // Green LED Goes Off
          servo1.attach(servoPin); //Servo is activated
          servo1.write(0);  //Servo turns on clockwise
            onTime = millis();  //time set
          }
      
      if(onTime > 0 && millis() - onTime > 1500)  //time limit target
            {      
            servo1.write(90); //Servo stops
            servo1.detach(); //servo deactivated
            delay(500); //used to sync the servo stop with the LED off
            digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);  // LED goes off
              onTime = 0;  //time reset
            }
            
if (digitalRead(buttonCpin) == LOW)   // Switch is closed to start LED timer
         {
          digitalWrite(GledPin, HIGH);  // Green LED comes On
          digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);  // RED LED Goes Off
          servo1.attach(servoPin); //Servo is activated
          servo1.write(180);  //Servo turns on anti-clockwise
            onTime = millis();  //time set
          }
      
      if(onTime > 0 && millis() - onTime > 1500)  //time limit target
            {                 
            servo1.write(90); //Servo stops
            servo1.detach(); //servo deactivated
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);
              onTime = 0;  //time reset
            }
            
if (digitalRead(buttonBpin) == LOW) //Deactivation Sequence KILL SWITCH
  {
    digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);
    servo1.write(90);
    servo1.detach();
      onTime = 0;  //time reset
  }
 


  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal?

  {
    switch(results.value)

    {

      case 0xFFE01F: // DOWN button pressed
                      {
          digitalWrite(RledPin, HIGH);  // Red LED comes On
          digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);  // Green LED Goes Off
          servo1.attach(servoPin); //Servo is activated
          servo1.write(0);  //Servo turns on clockwise
          onTime = millis();  //time set
          }
      
          if(onTime > 0 && millis() - onTime > 2000)  //time limit target
            {      
            servo1.write(90); //Servo stops
            servo1.detach(); //servo deactivated
            digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);  // LED goes off
             onTime = 0;  //time reset
            }
            break; 
                    

      case 0xFF906F: // UP button pressed
                      {
          digitalWrite(GledPin, HIGH);  // Green LED comes On
          digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);  // RED LED Goes Off
          servo1.attach(servoPin); //Servo is activated
          servo1.write(180);  //Servo turns on anticlockwise
          onTime = millis();  //time set
          }
      
      if(onTime > 0 && millis() - onTime > 2000)  //time limit target
            {      
            servo1.write(90); //Servo stops
            servo1.detach(); //servo deactivated
            digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);  // LED goes off
             onTime = 0;  //time reset
            } 
            break;

      case 0xFF02FD: // PAUSE button pressed
                      servo1.write(90);
                      servo1.detach();
                      digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);
                      digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);
                      break;
                
    }
    
      irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value


  
  }
}/* --end main loop -- */
```

Comment: insert a layer of separation between the button press and the resulting action ... do same with IR codes .... pressing a button results is a flag variable being set `doRed = true;` ...... `case 0xFFE01F:` does the same thing .... neither of these do anything else, just set a flag and continue on ..... further down in `loop()`, act on the state of the flag `if (doRed) {`

Comment: Please adopt an indenting style and stick to it. Your source is barely readable. Many problems reveal themselves by consistent indentation.

Comment: Insert some debugging outputs to see what exactly happens in your program.

Comment: Are you debouncing the buttons in hardware? If not, you need to debounce them in software using a [debouncer](https://github.com/TimMathias/Arduino-Debouncer). This will remove the random glitches as the switch contacts bounce when they change over.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the reply, sorry to sound silly but when you say add a layer of separation, what does that mean?

Comment: @tim Thanks for the suggestion, I ave read articles mentioning debouncers but don't know anything about them. I will go away and look into it, thank you.

Comment: @NathanCooper ... not separated `if button is pressed, then turn on LED`.... separated `if button is pressed, then set a flag` .... `if flag is set, then turn on LED` .... multiple events can set the flag ... only one function checks the flag and activates the LED

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer!

I added serial print to every line and realised that my kill process after the time elapsed was switching between the red led and green led.

I didn't need the if time elapsed function many times, just once. Deleted that portion and it worked perfectly. Seems to have fixed the IR troubles too.

Working code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo1;
int servoPin = 9;
#include "IRremote.h"

/*----- Variables, Pins -----*/


int receiver = 12; // Signal Pin of IR receiver to Arduino Digital Pin 6
int RledPin = 5;
int GledPin = 3;
int buttonApin = 7;
int buttonBpin = 8;
int buttonCpin = 4;
unsigned long elapsedTime;
unsigned long onTime;

/*-----( Declare objects )-----*/
// Setup of proper sequencing for Motor Driver Pins
// In1, In2, In3, In4 in the sequence 1-3-2-4

IRrecv irrecv(receiver);    // create instance of 'irrecv'
decode_results results;     // create instance of 'decode_results'

void setup()
{
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  servo1.attach(servoPin);
  servo1.write(90);
  pinMode(RledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonApin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
  pinMode(buttonBpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonCpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

}

void loop(){

if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW)   // Switch is closed to start LED timer
         {
          digitalWrite(RledPin, HIGH);  // Red LED comes On
          Serial.println("RED comes on");
          digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);  // Green LED Goes Off
          Serial.println("green off");
          servo1.attach(servoPin); //Servo is activated
          Serial.println("red servo attach");
          servo1.write(0);  //Servo turns on clockwise
          Serial.println("red servo spins");
            onTime = millis();  //time set
         }
      
if(onTime > 0 && millis() - onTime > 1500)  //time limit target
            {      
            servo1.write(90); //Servo stops
            Serial.println("servo stops spinning");
            digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);  // LED goes off
            digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);  // LED goes off
            Serial.println("red RED goes off");
            delay(500);
            Serial.println("delay");
            servo1.detach(); //servo deactivated
            Serial.println("servo Rled dettach");            
              onTime = 0;  //time reset
            
         }
if (digitalRead(buttonCpin) == LOW)   // Switch is closed to start LED timer
         {
          digitalWrite(GledPin, HIGH);  // Green LED comes On
          Serial.println("green comes on");
          digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);  // RED LED Goes Off
          Serial.println("RED goes off");
          servo1.attach(servoPin); //Servo is activated
          Serial.println("green servo attached");
          servo1.write(180);  //Servo turns on clockwise
          Serial.println("green servo spins");
            onTime = millis();  //time set
         }

            
if (digitalRead(buttonBpin) == LOW) //Dectivation Sequence KILL SWITCH
  {
    digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("total red off");
    digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("total green off");
    servo1.write(90);
    Serial.println("total servo off");
    servo1.detach();
    Serial.println("total detach");
      onTime = 0;  //time reset
  }
 


  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal?

  {
    switch(results.value)

    {

      case 0xFFE01F: // DOWN button pressed
                      {
          digitalWrite(RledPin, HIGH);  // Red LED comes On
          digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);  // Green LED Goes Off
          servo1.attach(servoPin); //Servo is activated
          servo1.write(0);  //Servo turns on clockwise
          onTime = millis();  //time set
          }
          break; 
                    

      case 0xFF906F: // UP button pressed
                      {
          digitalWrite(GledPin, HIGH);  // Green LED comes On
          digitalWrite(RledPin, LOW);  // RED LED Goes Off
          servo1.attach(servoPin); //Servo is activated
          servo1.write(180);  //Servo turns on clockwise
          onTime = millis();  //time set
          }
          break;

      case 0xFF02FD: // PAUSE button pressed
          servo1.write(90);
          digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(GledPin, LOW);
          delay(500);
          servo1.detach();         
          break;               
    }
    
      irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value


  
  }
}/* --end main loop -- */
```